# Open unknown type of file .REF

Tags: encryption, decoding

I need help opening some files I got.

I don't know the proper way to open it, all I know is that it's text based, as it's CAN-BUS info (Digits, 01 0F 3F 4D, etc [in example]). It may be encrypted some way I can't figure.

It's supposed to open with a external program to load this data.

Now the question is,

¿There is anyway to analyze it, metadata or whatever to decrypt it?

I don't know if it's permitted, but I will pay for a working solution as it's vital for my project right now.

I add some different files so you can analyze it.

http://www.racelogic.co.uk/_downloads/vbox/Vehicle_CAN_Files/Ford/2011%20Fiesta.REF

http://www.racelogic.co.uk/_downloads/vbox/Vehicle_CAN_Files/VAG/VW_CAN.REF

Example info in file in plain text:

```
    Racelogic Can Data File V1
   Unit serial number : 00000000
   xÚ30€  È  LxÚJM,Š÷IM+‰ÏHMÍ‰.HMMÑ1440Ô‰×16Ò14Ó1Ð1Ð300òÌÍÌut!Th^qfzP­o~I~Q~N¢ Z45 JxÚs+ÊÏ+‰ÏHMÍ)
   Ž.HMMÑ1440Ô‰×1±Ð14Ó1Ð1Ð300Ñ16273×Ñ…P¡yÅ™éy@µ¾ù%ùEù9‰: €D LxÚJM,ŠÊLÏ
   (‰ÏHMÍ‰.HMMÑ1440Ô‰×14!=c#s3s]šWœ™žTë›_’_”Ÿ“¨ |2ª ;xÚ
   ðÕ152Ð‰×1±Ð14Ó1Ð1Ð342Õ16273×Ñ…P¡yÅ™éy©):¾ù%ùEù9‰: xšë FxÚsLNNÍ‰HMI
  ’ùÅ™%™ùy:¦F:ññ:ÆF:::z¦:†Fæ:º "4¯83=/5EÇ7¿$¿(?'Q ³IV
```

This is an example of a CanBus file. (Note that previous .ref file, might be other format:

```
 865         8   0  86   3 220  96  21 125   0  
 929         8   0  27  32 128  24 134   4   0  
 194         6 109   4   0 127 255   1          
 326         8   0 255  64  12 255   0   3 130  
 358         8   0  44   0  44   0  44 128   0  
  70         8  16   0   0   0 128  32   0   0  
 865         8   0  86   3 231  95  21 125   0  
 929         8   0  27  32 128  24 133 244   0  
 194         6 126   4   0 127 255   1          
1378         2   0   0                          
 194         6 143   4   0 127 255   1          
 865         8   0  87   3 237  95  21 126   0  
 929         8   0  27  32 128  24 133 244   0
```

Comment: The Unix `file` command yielded no information; reported as "data"

Comment: The protocol is well-documented here - though could contain almost any device-specific data - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus

Answer (score 2):

#### It may be encrypted some way I can't figure

These REF files are encoded by [RaceLogic](http://www.racelogic.co.uk/index.php/en/). You are supposed to purchase them, and provide a CAN01 serial number. Presumably they will provide you with a key to decode them when you have paid ...

> It is also possible to import industry standard CAN database files with the “.DBC” file extension or **to purchase encoded data set files from Racelogic with the .REF extension.**

...

> Each Racelogic encoded CAN database (REF file) is locked to a specific CAN01 serial number. When ordering a REF file it is important to
>    specify the serial number of the CAN01 that it is to be used with.

Source [Vehicle CAN Bus Interface](http://www.racelogic.co.uk/_downloads/vbox/Manuals/Input_Modules/RLVBCAN01_Manual.pdf)

Comment: I already tried to ask them for purchase, but they are saying they're not selling... i was thinking about it could have some way to decypher but it seems not possible. Thanks anyway!